# No GUI after Debian Jessie installation

Tags: linux, debian, system-installation

So I finally decided to dip my toes into Linux and installed Debian Jesse. Most tutorials ended with their OS having GUI, etc just like windows. Mine does not. Lol I was greeted with just the command line, even though I gained root access it would not let me install any packages. Where should I go from here? Thanks!

Comment: What tutorial have you used? Or what were your installation steps?

Comment: it seems like you selected a minimal install instead of graphical install. You would need to re-install  it and select a graphical environment like xfce or kde

Comment: @ddnomad m.youtube.com/watch?v=kjFUKOhAjzc I followed this tutorial and a few others but pretty much followed all the step including installing with graphic. The only step that was missed was network config

Comment: @Francesc I did followed the graphical install though :/

Comment: @Francesc is probably right. What is the name of ISO file you've downloaded?

Comment: @ddnomad I used the auto download button on the Debian site and it downloaded the i386 file

Comment: @omegaD what is the exact name of a file? Also, when you boot the OS up, are there any errors?

Comment: then it's probably minimal install iso file.

Comment: @ddnomad debian-8.7.1-i386-netinst.iso

Comment: @Francesc how would I reinstall a new iso now?

Comment: @omegaD I'm sure it's a minimal installation ISO. As full ones have different names and are download with torrent.

Comment: @ddnomad so I should write a new iso file to disk and plug it in?

Comment: @omegaD are you using a VM or its a physical host?

Comment: @ddnomad physical sadly lol I have another computer though to write the disk but on the Debian right now I am stuck on the sources list

Comment: @omegaD you can use a thumb drive instead of a disk

Comment: @ddnomad ok no problem. So now how would I uninstall the minimal debian and reinstall graphical debian? Just plug in the new disk? Or do I have to prompt something first?

Comment: Basically, you just have to load a right ISO (with a full installation) to your thumb/disk and start the machine up from that device. Then click-click through installation process GUI and you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the i386 install is for ancient computers. Anything built in (at least) the last 10 years can - and probably should - [use the amd64 installation ISO](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-8.7.1-amd64-netinst.iso). That'll mean a fresh installation as you cannot regrade from i386 to amd64. However, bear in mind that Debian installation ISOs can also be copied directly to a USB stick and booted from there. So at least you don't need to burn a new CD/DVD.

It might be worth pointing out that the amd64 installation is suitable for any AMD/Intel 64bit system.

The Netinst is a minimal installation where the majority of the software is downloaded and installed from the Internet. Towards the end of the installation you would have been asked whether you wanted the GUI installed.

Assuming you have Internet access (otherwise how would you have had all the package and security updates applied?) you just need to run `tasksel` as root. The first option is "Debian desktop environment" and you need to select that and let it install the appropriate packages.

```
Package configuration

     ┌───────────────────────────────┤ Software selection ├───────────────────────────────┐
     │ You can choose to install one or more of the following predefined collections of   │
     │ software.                                                                          │
     │                                                                                    │
     │ Choose software to install:                                                        │
     │                                                                                    │
     │    [*] Debian desktop environment                                                  │
     │    [ ] Web server                                                                  │
     │    [ ] Print server                                                                │
     │    [ ] SQL database                                                                │
     │    [ ] DNS Server                                                                  │
     │    [ ] File server                                                                 │
     │    [ ] Mail server                                                                 │
     │    [ ] SSH server                                                                  │
     │    [ ] Laptop                                                                      │
     │                                                                                    │
     │                                                                                    │
     │                                       <Ok>                                         │
     │                                                                                    │
     └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes I think my problem was that I installed the iso without internet. I do have a ethernet cable plugged in now. Can you teach me how to configure my network?

Comment: @omegad wipe the system and install the amd64 version. Treat the first attempt as a practice run.

Comment: yes thank you so much! I reinstalled the amd64 and got my full desktop. Now just have to connect to wifi

Comment: @roaima I get the `tasksel: apt-get failed (100)` error with the similar effort. What to do now?

Comment: @Arefe if your system doesn't have Internet access don't try using the Netinst ISO